# Can a python for loop affect the final dataframe result

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, nested-loops

I have found that these two pseudo code scripts produce to different results.

Script 1:

```
# Load dataframe
Df_1 = read_csv(path to file.csv)
# Start iteration through list of dates
For date in range(250):
    Df_1 = Function_that_calculates_stuff(Df_1)
    # Grab data I’m interested in and save to text file
    row = pd.DataFrame([[str(Df_1.iloc[1,1]), ]])
    Txt_file = Txt_file.append(row, ignore_index = True)

# After loop, save dataframes
Df_1.to_csv(path to file.csv)
```

Script 2:

```
For number in range(250):
   For date in range(1):
     # Load dataframe
     Df_1 = read_csv(path to file.csv)
     Df_1 = Function_that_calculates_stuff(Df_1)
     # Grab data I’m interested in and save to text file
     row = pd.DataFrame([[str(Df_1.iloc[1,1]), ]])
     Txt_file = Txt_file.append(row, ignore_index = True)
     Df_1.to_csv(path to file.csv)
```

I’m stumped why this is. I have tried walking through the code one line at a time, but have been unable to find anything that could explain this.

Can a nested loop alter the data loaded or saved in them?

And is there a way to create a sort of dam that prevents unwanted data from “leaking” to the start of the loop.

Comment: These are not operating the same way, In the first exmaple you open the file once and load the data. you will then iterate over the rows reallocating the result to DF_1, essentially like a filtering style. So in each iteration of the loop, it will act on the data in DF_1 based on the last loop. However in the second example, you always start each loop with a fresh copy of the data loaded from the file, not the data that was left over form the last loop. So these may operate very different.

Answer (score 0):

The two code snippits you provided dont do the same thing. Essentially in the first code snippet you read the data once from the file. We will call this the initial state. Then for each iteration of the loop you call the function passing it the data and then store the result back into the same variable thus overwritting the data.

So when the next iteration starts you will be using the data form the last iteration of the loop not the inital data loaded from the file. this will continue like a filtering or reduction process. each iteration may reduce or enrich the data form the last loop.

In your second code you are always loading the data form the file. So each iteration of the loop is applied to the original data not acting upon the data on the previous data form the previous loop.

As you dont give much in your example to reproduce the issue I have constructed a simple example to demonstrate this

```py
def divides_by_i(num_data, i):
    return [num for num in num_data if num % i == 0]


data = ("0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"
        "10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,"
        "20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30")

nums_data = [int(num) for num in data.split(",")]

for i in range(1, 4):
    nums_data = divides_by_i(nums_data, i)
with open("out1.txt", "w") as out1:
    out1.write(",".join(str(num) for num in nums_data))

for i in range(1, 4):
    for _ in range(1):
        nums_data = [int(num) for num in data.split(",")]
        nums_data = divides_by_i(nums_data, i)
        with open("out2.txt", "w") as out1:
            out1.write(",".join(str(num) for num in nums_data))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
First loop: 0,6,12,18,24,30
Second loop: 0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30
```

In the first loop it takes all the data and overwrites it with data that is divisable the number of that loop iteration. The next iteration will act only on the numbers from the previous iteration. we write the data at the end to a file.

In the second loop it always reads the data from the original numbers and applies the result and then saves the result of this iteration over any other output. So essentially in the second loop the function will act on the original data and apply the function and save the output each time, meaning you lose any output from the previous loop.

So the issue is not with the fact that you have a nested loop, its the fact that your opening your file only once in the first example and opening it on each iteration in the second example. If you move that open back to outside the loops it will act the same.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for taking the time to clarify this for me. In my second example I load the dataframe in iteration 0. Lets call it DF(0), put it through the function and then save it. Then when the loop starts over, it loads the dataframe again, though it contain the data from DF(0). Now it puts it through the function, resulting in DF(1). It saves again and start over. How is this different than example 1?

Comment: In the second loop on each iteration you load DF_1 from the file `Df_1 = read_csv(path to file.csv)` then you update the value of Df_1 with the function result `Df_1 = Function_that_calculates_stuff(Df_1)` So by the end of the iteration, `Df_1` is now the value of the result from the function not the data from the file. however on the next iteration, you again load the file putting `Df_1` back to the original data and losing the data you put in it on the previous iteration

Comment: I end each iteration in example 2, with a `Df_1.to_csv(path to file.csv)` and start the loop over by loading it again with `Df_1 = read_csv(path to file.csv)`. So I am then not "losing" the data if I understand correctly.

Comment: Ah sorry i see what you mean now

Comment: yeah in that case it should work, what kind of difference are you seeing